# Making a field read only through jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am working in Django and populated the labels of the forms . Then I need one Field which is the "country" to be read only so that no one can edit that .
I applied the following code but its not working . can some one help ?

```js
jQuery12(".input_id_shipping_detail_country label").replaceWith("*Country");
```

This one is for replacing the label its working fine

```js
<script>
jQuery1 = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery1(window).load(function () {
    jQuery1("#id_billing_detail_country").val('Mexico');
}); 
</script>
{% else %}

<script>
jQuery1 = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery1(window).load(function () {
    jQuery1("#id_billing_detail_country").val('United States');
}); 
</script>
```

This is for the default value load at onload function of window .

```js
country(document).ready(function() 
{
    country('#id_billing_detail_country')
        .replaceWith(country('#id_billing_detail_country')
        .clone().attr('readonly', 'readonly'));
    country('#id_shipping_detail_country')
        .replaceWith(country('#id_shipping_detail_country')
        .clone().attr('readonly', 'readonly'));
    country("#id_billing_detail_country").css("border", "none");
    country("#id_shipping_detail_country").css("border", "none");
```

Now this is the code where I applied the read-only thing its not working .
I have tried `.prop` instead of `.attr` as well.

Comment: I guess, bold text is supposed to show how important the question is for you and for the whole community?

Comment: Yes Its important to me

Comment: If you're highlighting _everything_, are you really highlighting anything?

Comment: `.prop()` seems like it should work - can you show how you've used it and discuss what went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is use `prop()` like this:

```
$('.myselector').prop('readonly', true);
```

Change `.myselector` to target whatever input field(s) you need to make read-only.

[Here it is working in jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw5ew/)

Answer (score 0):

I uused it like this on window.load   and it worked .

```
   <script>
    jQuery12 = jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery12(window).load(function () {
    jQuery12("#id_billing_detail_country").val('Mexico').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    jQuery12("#id_shipping_detail_country").val('Mexico').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    jQuery12('#id_same_billing_shipping').prop('checked', false);
    }); 
    </script>
```

Thanks All

Comment: Did you try @ChrisLTD’s answer at all?